# Estou tendo dificuldade em compilar um programa simples em C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int y = 5;
int *yPtr;

printf("Address of y veriable: %x \n",&y);

printf("Address stored in yPtr variable: %x \n", yPtr);

printf("Value of y: %d\n", y);

printf("Value of *& yPtr : %x \n", *&yPtr);
printf("Value of &* yPtr : %x \n", &*yPtr);

return 0;
}
```

Na hora da compilação o compilador mostra a seguinte mensagem:

```
(format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("Value of &* yPtr : %x \n", &*yPtr);
                            ~^
                            %ls).
```

Eu queria porque o compilador mostra esse aviso para usar `%ls`.

Comment: Mas o que você esperava que acontecesse quando faz `printf("Value of &* yPtr : %x \n", &*yPtr);` ? Qual era o resultado que você tinha em mente ?

Comment: um resultado em Hexadecimal

Comment: e qual seria o valor ? e esse valor representa o que ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No y, não precisa do "&" no printf, e coloque "%d" visto que é do tipo int

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int y = 5;
int *yPtr;

printf("Address of y veriable: %d \n",y);

printf("Address stored in yPtr variable: %d \n", yPtr);

printf("Value of y: %d\n", y);

printf("Value of  yPtr : %d \n", &yPtr);
printf("Value of  yPtr : %d \n", &yPtr);

return 0;
}
```